# Offline printers no longer visible

Tags: kubuntu, printing

In Kubuntu 18.04, my wifi printer Canon MX920, when offline, was still showing on Settings (but as "Inactive"). I could print anything (or my scripts using lpr), and my laptop held the jobs until I started the printer.

[Kubuntu 18.04: Printer available to print even offline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ELn9.png)

But on Kubuntu 20.04, offline printers are no longer there (even if manually added), so I can't "send to print later".

Any idea of how can I keep the printer available even when offline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I've found is to install Cups' Gutenprint drivers and add a new (default) printer using those drivers. But Ubuntu keeps adding another printer using "driverless" drives.